# Certificate validation prompt is not displayed

Tags: svn, openssl, ssl-certificate

My SVN server's certificate has expired and it was replaced by newer certificate. Earlier, I was able to connect to the server after accepting serer certificate. Now, since certificate has been updated, I need to accept it again. When I try to run any svn command (svn list), trust server certificate prompt is not displayed. Instead, an error is displayed stating that SSL handshake failed. 
How can I make svn display the prompt or accept certificate in svn? I also tried --trust-server-cert option to no use.

I am receiving following error:

> SSL handshake failed: SSL error code -1/1/336032856

Comment: What OpenSSL version is installed on the server?

Comment: I am not sure how can I check it. I tried openssl s_client command though and I was able to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that the newer certificate's hostname matches VisualSVN Server's server name.
2. Upgrade your SVN client.

Comment: upgrading svn client fixed the issue. Thanks.